# Let $S(m,n)$ be the number of ways we can distribute m distinct objects into n identical containers in such a way that no container is left empty.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S(m,n)$ be the number of ways we can distribute m distinct objects into n identical containers in
such a way that no container is left empty. Prove that for 
$1 < n ≤ m: S(m+1, n) = S(m, n−1)+nS(m, n)$

I'm having troubles figuring out how to prove this. It looks similar to Pascal's formula where $\dbinom{m+1}{n} = \dbinom{m}{n-1} + \dbinom{m}{n}$ but I don't see where the n comes from where $nS(m,n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the $m+1$ element, because the $n$ containers are identical, then you can consider only the two cases where the $m+1$ element is alone in a container, and the case where is not.

It should not be too hard to map what $S(m,n-1)$ and $nS(m,n)$ means in these terms.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. So if the m+1 element is in it's own container, then there would be m objects in n containers, but if it was not in it's own, there would be m + 1 objects in n containers, so there would have to be one container with a minimum of two objects in it?

Comment: Edit: Never mind, I figured it out. Thanks for your help